# How do i print this array output

Tags: php, arrays

I am new to PHP and was not sure how to search for this answer.

I am trying to print the "ip" variable from the `var_dump` below.

```
array(1) { [0]=> array(5) { ["host"]=> string(33) "lb19-d" ["class"]=> string(2) "IN" ["ttl"]=> int(6629) ["type"]=> string(1) "A" ["ip"]=> string(10) "76.96.32.8" } }
```

This is the code i am using to get the output, where `$all_addresses` is an array or hostnames:

`$dns = dns_get_record("$all_address", DNS_A);`

`var_dump($dns);`

Comment: have you tried var_dump($dns['ip']) ?

Comment: Try var_dump($dns[0]['ip'])

Comment: Lets assume your array variable is $array, to get the IP you would do : echo $array[0]['ip'];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just access it using keys:

```
echo $dns[0]['ip'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to go into key 0. You could do like this:

```
echo $dns[0]['ip'];
```